# how to improve query performance when using HAVING and MIN combined

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison

I have a very slow and simple query that I'm trying to improve, its purpose is to obtain the date at a Unit failed for first time and is the following:

```
select unit_id, min(fail_Date) fail_Date
    from failures
  having min(fail_date) between '24-aug-2012' and '25-aug-2012'
   group by unit_id
```

as you may guess Unit_id is not unique, is the foreign key to identify the unit that has failed, and in this table I have multiple records for the same unit if it failed multiple times.

I know this is not the best way to do this but I have no control over the tables and I must work with them as they are.

this table has a index for the fail_date and for the unit_id.

Despite that, this query takes 10 seconds, I was thinking to just ask, how can I make it faster? but then I came to this way to query the values and it only takes 0.03 seconds:

```
with fail_dates as
 (select unit_id, fail_date
    from failures
   where fail_date between '24-aug-2012' and '25-aug-2012')
select f.unit_id, min(f.fail_Date) fail_Date
  from fail_dates
 inner join failures f
    on fail_dates.unit_id= f.unit_id
 group by f.unit_id,fail_dates.fail_date
 having  min(f.fail_Date) = fail_dates.fail_date
```

they both return exactly the same records, but the second one is 10 times faster, 
now my question is, are this two queries really equivalent???  and why the second is way much faster?

thank you!

Comment: Always use ranges in the form 'lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive', and avoid the use of `BETWEEN` like the plague, especially for dates/timestamps.  This helps prevent 'fencepost' errors, as well as having to deal with milliseconds...  You also shouldn't need the second column in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: nm, you do need that second column in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I think your query is a perfect candidate for views materialization. It's simple, it is amenable for views materialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*My conclusions have changed and this answer has been largely re-written.*

At first I thought your 2 queries were different, but after reading your comment and re-examining the 2nd query I realize it will indeed give the same results. Both queries only return units whose earliest failure is within the 2 day range.

Your first query is slow because it logically must look at all failure dates for each unit. It may be performing a full table (or index) scan.

Your second query is much faster because it only computes the minimum fail date for units that had a failure within the target date range. I would guess it is using an index with fail date on the leading edge to identify units with a failure in the target range. Then it can use an index with unit id on the leading edge to look for the minimum fail date for relevant units.

The following query should be equivalent to your queries, and it has the potential to be a bit faster than your 2nd query, though I wouldn't count on it. I say it might be faster because this query can eliminate a unit as soon as it finds any record with an early fail date, whereas your 2nd query must logically look at all fail dates for the unit. As long as this query is not slower than your 2nd query, I would choose this because I think the logic is more straight forward and easier to follow.

```
select unit_id,
       min(fail_Date) fail_Date
  from failures f
 where fail_date between '24-aug-2012' and '25-aug-2012'
   and not exists (
          select 1
            from failures f2
           where f2.unit_id=f1.unit_id
             and f2.fail_date < '24-aug-2012'
       )
 group by unit_id
```

Comment: thanks for your query ill test it as soon as i get at work, 
but in the mean time please double check my second query, in this part "having  min(f.fail_Date)= " im doing something similar as your subquery... are you sure mine is incorrect?.

Comment: @montelof - OMG - you are correct. I didn't look at your join condition carefully and assumed you were joining on both the unit id and the fail date. Now I realize you are just using unit id. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think your original query could be improved if you rewrote it as

```
select unit_id, min(fail_Date) fail_Date
  from failures
  where fail_date between '24-aug-2012' and '25-aug-2012'
  group by unit_id
```

I would expect this to perform about as well as your second query.  The reason this query and your second query run faster is because you first subset the table by choosing only those records which have FAIL_DATE in the desired range - this probably allows an index to be used.  The original query has to scan the entire table since there is no WHERE clause to help it pick out only the records of interest.

You might want to look at the EXPLAIN PLAN output for the two queries to see how they're being evaluated.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Your query won't get _exactly_ the same results as the OP's does, as there may be a 'minimum' failure date _before_ the indicated range.

Comment: actually it wont return the same results because it will include some rows that their minimum date could be outside the data range and should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking too closely at them, I'd say they're equivalent in the sense that, right now, they return the same rows. Don't count on that to continue.

But the common table expression (CTE) in the second version has a very restrictive WHERE clause in it, selecting rows for only two days. That restrictive WHERE clause should greatly reduce the work that GROUP BY and HAVING have to do.

You should be able to tell for sure by looking at the [execution plan](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/focus-areas/bi-datawarehousing/twp-explain-the-explain-plan-052011-393674.pdf) (pdf, whitepaper).

Comment: that's true, Ill try to test an extended period of time to see if they actually return the same rows, because it could be that, all the units for this date range failed the first time in the same day. but what if they fail on different day also? one fail will be included in the fail_dates view, but should be ignored because it was not the first time they fail. if that's the case, then there is no way to improve the first slow query.

Comment: even that i wrote the second query im still dont quite understand exactly how it works, but it seems that this part "having  min(f.fail_Date) = " will prevent that units that fail before the date range are included in the results, as I said in the previous comment. so it looks like it should work for any data range...for now.

Comment: Ill be very amazed if this queries are actually equivalent because this conversion could apply to anyone having the same problem as me, for a combination of HAVING with MIN.